# MongoDB get values with most recent date

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with documents such as [these](https://pastebin.com/RtD7hKg1).
What I want to do is get all distinct `clusters` coming from the document with the highest (recent) `lastupdate` field.
I think this should be the output:

```
[
    "19":"Income2",
    "20":"Income Modified",
    "21":"Income Modified"
]
```

Comment: Which two fields do those represent in your data structure? Clusters and what else? Period?

Comment: As shown in pastebin clusters is an array with the Ids and then I have the "lastupdate" as as separte field

Comment: I see. I think the fact that your schema doesn't allow for a unique name within the array object, it makes using `.distinct` ineffective. Perhaps a structure like `{ClusterId: "19", ClusterType: "Income Modified"}` Would better suit you. Perhaps there's a solution here as it stands and I'm unaware of it.

Comment: I totally agree with you. However this is how the data comes.

Comment: In the JSON, the latest 'last_update' time is 1564669907375. That document only has 2 clusters information. So the output should be `[{"19":"Income2"},{"21":"Income Modified"}]` right??

Comment: Actually not, because I want to get each single cluster whose document has the highest lastupdate. Documents can have different clusters, hence I want to pick the common and uncommon ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this :

```
db.yourCollection.aggregate([{ $unwind: '$meta.clusters' },
{ $project: { '_id': { $objectToArray: '$meta.clusters' }, 'last_update': 1 } }, { $sort: { 'last_update': -1 } },
{ $group: { _id: '$_id.k', values: { $first: '$$ROOT' } } }, { $sort: { 'values.last_update': -1 } },
{ $replaceRoot: { 'newRoot': '$values' } },
{ $group: { _id: '', distinctCLusters: { $push: { $arrayToObject: "$_id" } } } }, { $project: { _id: 0 } }])
```

Output with provided data:

```
{
    "distinctCLusters" : [  
        {
            "21" : "Income Modified"
        },
        {
            "19" : "Income2"
        },
        {
            "20" : "Income Modified"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are close to what expected, there is a `19:Income1 ` not expected because has low lastupdate

Comment: @3nomis : Did it work or are you still seeing any issue ?

Comment: @ srinivas y thanks for your reply, I am sure it is going to be correct. As I get back to work on monday I'll try and sure let you know. Thanks for your help